# How do I create a single generic repository that will serve 2 teams for artifact deployment

Tags: repository, artifactory

In Artifactory, how do I create a single generic repository that will serve 2 teams for artifact deployment - each team needs to have access to only their team-specific artifacts.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible. You need to make use of Include/Exclude patterns.
You can create a permission target that gives access only to the specific path.
Admin > permission target > Create new > add the repository(generic in your case) > Remove the default include pattern **/* and add your include pattern > path2/** > Add the relevant user or group to this permssions target > save it.

If the user logsin now, he will be able to view only his artifacts under the path.
Also, depending on your usecase, you may want to remove the default read access in user permissions.
[image]

[image]
[image]
For other team, you need to create another permission target with the path you want.